# Simultaneous eval and exec

Tags: python, eval, exec

Is there a way to get python to do an evaluation and execution on a string?  I have a file which contains a bunch of expressions that need to be calculated, maybe something like this.

```
f1(ifilter(myfilter,x))
f2(x)*f3(f4(x)+f5(x))
```

I run through the file and `eval` the expressions.

Some of the expressions may want to save their work after doing an expensive operation

```
y = g(x); h(y)+j(y)
```

Unfortunately, `y=g(x)` requires an `exec`, but getting the value of `h+j` is an `eval`.  How does this work?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the builtin `compile()`. When you use it in single mode it handles both of the cases that you want. For example:

```
compile('3+4','<dummy>','single')
```

will return a compiled code object. You can execute it with exec() or eval() :

```
>>> exec(compile('3+4','<dummy>','single'))
7
>>> exec(compile('x=3+4','<dummy>','single'))
>>> print x
7
```

Comment: Actually the `'single'` mode *prints* the repr of the result of an expression in an expression statement, so it might not do whatever OP wants.

Comment: No it does not at all. I suggest that you read the docs and then try the example that I listed 5 years ago. You will note that setting the value of x proves that the code does not do what you have claimed.

Comment: The exec from the *first* example prints the value, and obviously does not return it.

Comment: Oh course! My apologies as I never spotted the difference when I tried it in the interpreter. With a few more years experience I would say the answer is quite simple - try an eval, and when it throws an exception do it again with an exec. Oh well...

Comment: The problem still is that the value of the last expression is not returned, so it is not that simple.

Comment: In which case the problem is not how to do both exec/eval on the same string. The problem is how to encode the expressions in a better way. Using an explicit 'retval' and applying exec to everything with a custom namespace would be the cleanest way. The alternative is to check the code object and see if the expression / statement can be distinguished in the bytecode.